# Limit Search Centre to people and one list

Tags: 2010, search, search-scope, people-search

I have a search box on my intranet that is pointing to a basic search centre, however, when you search it's searching through all content and bringing back things like images etc but I on the search I only want it to look it at the my sites to bring back staff details and one document directory, not all sites.

I've created the scope, linked it to the search centre but it won't remove the all sites.

Can any one point me in the direction of where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the scope correctly and then changed the Search Results Web part to use that scope it should only return results from the scope. I would recheck the scope and the settings on the results web part.